# Loop to do the same action to 3 different objects in Python

Tags: python

I don't exactly know how to express what I'm trying to do.

Instead of:

```py
motor1.setRegister(0x00)
motor2.setRegister(0x00)
motor3.setRegister(0x00)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```py
motor = ["motor1", "motor2", "motor3"]

for i in motor:

    motor[i].setRegister(0x00)
```

Unfortunately this is giving me an error `(AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setRegister')`.

How could I do that properly?

Comment: Store the motor objects (not the variable names) in a list instead of using single variables at all.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. It seems that the error you report cannot come from the code you have posted.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How would you do that? Thank you!

Comment: `motors = [motor1, motor2, motor3]`, followed by `for motor in motors: motor.setRegister(0x00)`.

Comment: btw Your question title seems to describe exactly what you intend for your code.

Comment: You can use globals() as well, for example:
globals()['motor1'].setRegister(0x00)

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `motor = ["motor1", "motor2", "motor3"]`, what do you think this means? In particular, what sorts of things are contained inside the `motor` list? Are they motors, or strings? If you were to take an object out of this list - for example by doing `motor[i]` - and try to `.setRegister` it, what kind of thing should it be? If this is the code that you use to put strings into the list, what code would you use instead to put motors inside the list? (Hint: do you already have some variables that name those motors, that you could use for this part of the code?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I read your reply many times. I'm sure it's extremely simple but I honestly can't figure it out. As I understood, I must create a list of objects instead of a list of strings. But I'm using a library to create each object (motor1, motor2, motor3)... I do motor1 = stChain.create(0), same for 2 and 3. Could you please give me another hint? Thank you

Comment: @Zerpudo Matthias already gave you exactly the answer I am trying to guide you towards; you should try to think more clearly in order to understand how it applies.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I feel so stupid. Thank you! I can't believe I did not see the absence of double quotes in the list that he posted. That way he is referring to the objects themselves and not their name as strings. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zerpudo It was a pleasure. :) And please reread the questions from Karl Knechtel in the comments and keep them in mind until you are able to answer them. This will help you in the long run.